# Laravel sortBy() based on string values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel application, a shirt has many sizes:

```
public function sizes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Size::class, 'size_id');
}
```

A size has an attribute called `name` that can be SM, MD, LG, XL, XXL, etc.

I would like to append a `sortBy()` to the eloquent relationship, so that sizes always appear in order from SM up to XXL.

Is it possible to write a sort based on string values? I've only ever written them based on whether one value was greater than another, but that obviously doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

results can be sorted by strings using a `case`:

```
 public function sizes(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Size::class, 'size_id')->orderByRaw(DB::raw("
        CASE name WHEN 'SM' THEN 1
               WHEN 'MD' THEN 2
               WHEN 'LG' THEN 4
               WHEN 'XL' THEN 5
               WHEN 'XXL' THEN 6
     ELSE 7 END ASC"));
    }
```

There are shorter options but they aren't available for every database implementation:

- Mariadb: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/find_in_set/
- Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

> Mysql

The `find_in_set` for mysql would look like this:

```
return $this->hasMany(\App\Size::class, 'size_id')->orderByRaw(DB::raw("find_in_set(name,'SM','MD','LG','XL', 'XXL')"));
```

> MariaDB

```
return $this->hasMany(\App\Size::class, 'size_id')->orderByRaw(DB::raw("find_in_set(name,'SM,MD,LG,XL,XXL')"));
```